# ByteBuf allocator in Reactor Netty

Tags: project-reactor, reactor-netty

Is there a way of getting ahold of the ByteBuf allocator used in Reactor Netty in a request handler? Similar to how one can do `final ByteBufAllocator byteBufAllocator = ctx.alloc();` in pure Netty?

```
HttpServer.create()
        .host("0.0.0.0")
        .port(8080)
        .route(routes -> {
          routes.ws("/ws", (in, out) ->  
            // how to get the allocator here?
          });
        })
```

Comment: Please specify server or client and on what stage do you want to obtain it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, clarified the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `ByteBufAllocator` from the `WebSocketOutbound` or `HttpServerResponse` like this:

```
HttpServer.create()
        .host("0.0.0.0")
        .port(8080)
        .route(routes -> routes
                .ws("/ws", (in, out) -> {
                    ByteBufAllocator alloc = out.alloc();
                    // ...
                })
                .get("/path", (request, response) -> {
                    ByteBufAllocator alloc = response.alloc();
                    // ...
                })
        );
```